# How can I update a ASP.NET MVC ViewData via jQuery ajax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, jquery

I have a page that highly depends on a IList (in ActionResult "MyEvents") that I pass in ViewData. Something like that: **ViewData["events"] = listOfEvents;** and in the end, I just **return View();**

And in my View, I take this ViewData["events"] and do a foreach in it so I can iterate through its contents.

But, this ViewData must be dynamically filled. So, when I click on a day (I'm using jQuery DatePicker), this day is sent as an argument to "MyEvents" and this day will be very important to my listOfEvents that will fill my ViewData["events"].

But, the result I'm getting is that the div that contains my foreach creates another whole page inside it!! I've tried to do **$("#myDiv").html(contentFromMyEvents)** and this was what happened.

Just for testing, I've tried also to do **$("#myDiv").text(contentFromMyEvents)** and the whole html code with all its tags and everyting else from my page appeared inside the div! It was a page inside a page!!

So, I think that is happening because I'm returning "**return View();**" and of course it will render my whole View again.

So, how can I pass just the ViewData["events"] and update it on my page??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look to the load function in jQuery(http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load).  Call your controller with load and then inject the result into your html document.

```
$("myDiv").load("/Controller/Action");
```

Your ViewData will be parsed on the server side. Instead of returning View(), return a PartialView() pointing to a user control. What comes out then is just a HTML fragment.

Comment: This way will work but I personally think it is a bad practice to send html over the pipe.

Comment: Agreed.  I think there might be some circumstances where my example is acceptable though.  I just provided it for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Thinking about this a little more, I used this technique recently when I needed to inline an existing entry form into another form.  The form layout was already in another view, and I just needed a modal with that same GUI for a "quick add" feature.

Comment: Thanks Josh! I just modified a little bit what you've told me, but I used much of your tip!! Thanks you too Kelly!

Answer (score 1):

You could use partial rendering or you could have jquery select the element from the return value.

```
$("#myDiv").empty().append($(contentFromMyEvents).find('#myDiv'));
```

Also, keep in mind that if you have any datepickers or links that require events inside of here you may have to rebind them.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into passing data back and forth as [JSON](http://json.org).

Then using jQuery/Javascript to manipulate and format the data as you see fit.

Remember that once the page is on the client the client's browser has no idea what ViewData is.

**Edit:**
Action Code:

```
public ActionResult AjaxGetEvents(int id)
{
    IList<object> events = new List<object>();
    foreach( Event event in SomeMethodToGetEvents(id) )
    {
       events.Add( new { Property1 = event.Property1, Property2 = event.Property2 } );
    }
    return JSON(events);
}
```

Client Side Code:

```
var url = "some url that returns JSON";
jQuery.getJSON( url, function(data){
    jQuery.each( data ){
        jQuery("#someDiv").append( data.Property1 + " " + data.Property2 "<br/>" );
    });
 });
```

Comment: Kelly, I'm doing this when I ckick on a day:
$.ajax({ 
       url: 'Admin/Schedule/MyEvents/?data=' + date,
       type: 'GET',
       success: function(content) { $("#myDiv").html(content) 
)};

It's something like that. The problem is that "return View();" (in my ActionResult) is (continues...)

Comment: (continuing...) is returning my whole page to that "success" $.ajax option. 
I think I've got to return any other kind of data in my ActionResult... I don't know, maybe "return JSON (ViewData["events"]);" ???

Comment: In my page I'm doing this:

foreach (UserEvents event in (IEnumerable)ViewData["events"]) { //do all iteration here }...

So, how can I get a JSON and treat this ViewData???