# How can I update/refresh ViewData in my ASP.NET Core Razor View?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have followed the advice given in the comment and created a `PartialView`. When running the debugger I can see that `@Model` at some point in time gets filled with the content of the `reply` variable. However, it never shows up on the page!!! What am I doing wrong here?

```
// Pages\Shared\_ReplyPartial.cshtml

<h1>Response</h1>

<p>@Model</p>
```

Then this is what my PageModel looks like

```
// Dependencies.cshtml.cs

public class DependenciesModel : PageModel
{
    ... 
    
    public PartialViewResult OnGetCreateBlob()
    {
        ... 

        var response = _client.PutAsync(url, new StringContent(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString())).Result;     
        var reply = $"StatusCode: {(int)response.StatusCode}";

        return Partial("_ReplyPartial", reply);
    }
}
```

And finally the page itself

```
// Dependencies.cshtml

@page
@model AppInsightsDemo.Pages.DependenciesModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Dependencies";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $('#createBlob').on('click', () => {
            $.ajax({
                url: '?handler=CreateBlob'
            });
        });
    </script>
}


<button class="btn btn-primary mb-1" id="createBlob">Create Blob</button>

<partial name="_ReplyPartial">
```

---

**ORIGINAL POST**

Please consider the following code, where I am making an AJAX call to call `OnGetCreateBlob()` from the code behind.

```
//// Site.cshtml

@page
@model Demo.Pages.SiteModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Dependencies";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).click(e => {
            if (e.target.id == "createBlob") {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '?handler=CreateBlob'
                });    
            }
        });
    </script>
}

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="createBlob">Create Blob</button>

<h1>Response</h1>

<div id="response">
    @ViewData["Reply"]
</div>
```

```
//// Site.cshtml.html 

public class SiteModel : PageModel
{
    ... 

    public void OnGetCreateBlob()
    {
        ...

        var response = _client.PutAsync(url, new StringContent(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString())).Result;

        var statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
        var reply = $"StatusCode: {statusCode}";

        ViewData["Reply"] = reply;
    }
}
```

The thing is, the `ViewData` is not getting updated on the view.

I've tried to refresh the window with `window.location.reload()` just after executing the AJAX call, however then it seems the content of `ViewData` is lost.

If I do an `$("#response").load(location.href + " #response");` and just reload the `div` nothing appears.

So how can I display the content of `ViewData` after it got populated by the code behind?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539011/how-can-i-update-a-asp-net-mvc-viewdata-via-jquery-ajax check this may help

Comment: You have here also an example with explanations why you should return a "PartialViewResult". https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/partial-update

Answer (score 1):

Yo can try to replace `<partial name="_ReplyPartial">` after ajax.Here is a demo:

Dependencies.cshtml:

```
@page
@model AppInsightsDemo.Pages.DependenciesModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Dependencies";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $('#createBlob').on('click', () => {
            $.ajax({
                url: '?handler=CreateBlob',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#partial").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}


<button class="btn btn-primary mb-1" id="createBlob">Create Blob</button>
<div id="partial">
    <partial name="_ReplyPartial">
</div>
```

You can also replace `@ViewData["Reply"]` in  Site.cshtml after ajax.Here is a demo:

Site.cshtml:

```
@page
@model Demo.Pages.SiteModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Dependencies";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).click(e => {
            if (e.target.id == "createBlob") {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '?handler=CreateBlob',
                     success: function (data) {
                        $("#response").html(data);
                    }
                });    
            }
        });
    </script>
}

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="createBlob">Create Blob</button>

<h1>Response</h1>

<div id="response">
    @ViewData["Reply"]
</div>
```

Site.cshtml.cs:

```
public class SiteModel : PageModel
{
    ... 

    public IActionResult OnGetCreateBlob()
    {
        ...

        var response = _client.PutAsync(url, new StringContent(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString())).Result;

        var statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
        var reply = $"StatusCode: {statusCode}";

        ViewData["Reply"] = reply;
        return Content(reply);
    }
}
```